# get first image on custom post type

Tags: wordpress

I have this custom post type Gallery. I want to call first image from the posts.

```
<?php 
$item_count = 1;
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'gallery', 'posts_per_page' => 10 );  
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
$item_count = 1;
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  ?>
    <?php the_title();  ?>
    <div class="count"><?php echo $item_count; ?></div>
    <div class="thumbnail">
    // THE FIRST GALLERY ATTACHMENT IMAGE
    </div> 

<?php $item_count++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Any ideas?

Note: I added Gallery no simple image on the post!

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children#Show_the_first_image_associated_with_the_post) WordPress Codex example.

The code will show the first image associated with the post.

Or check [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/retreive-first-image-from-post?replies=25) WordPress forum discussion that also deals with this problem.

**UPDATE:**

Go to **Appearance > Editor** and select Theme functions (functions.php).
at the end of the file add this:

```
// Get URL of first image in a post
function catch_that_image($my_postid) {
global $post;


$first_img = '';
  ob_start();
  ob_end_clean();
            $output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i',  get_post_field('post_content', $my_postid), $matches);

$first_img = $matches [1] [0];

// no image found display default image instead
if(empty($first_img)){

$first_img = "/images/default.jpg";
}
return $first_img;
} ?>
```

Now in your code you modify this part of the code:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
   <?php echo catch_that_image($loop->ID) ?>
</div>
```

**UPDATE V2**

I modified the code to suit your code.

**UPDATE V3**

I tried the code on my development site and I modified it further until the code worked as it should. You should not have any problems now.

Comment: Thanks. But i`m beginner in php and in the wordpress. Please add more details. And my problem to query with custom post type and first image.

Comment: Unfortunatelly is not working... no image found :(. Why? This code i already tested. Thanks ---- NOTE: In the post its added Gallery as attachment no simple images.

Comment: It's midnight here so I forgot to modify the code to your needs. I updated it now, hope it will work:)

Comment: Hy, Thanks for your time but its working only with simple image in the post but with gallery not working. I want with gallery [gallery ids="119,86,81,63,19,9,121"]. I want to call the first image from the gallery. Thanks. I appreciated for your time. :)

Comment: Frankly to say, the 3 days all I look for the solution but I not found :( for this issue....

Comment: Never used galleries before. Maybe this will help you: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/19893/28218