# Getting first Image from custom post type gallery attachement

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, image-gallery

I have created custom post type `"albums"` in wordpress theme. An Image gallery is attached to each post successfully. All images attached to all parent post inside gallery are display on front-end using:

```
<ul id="gallery">    
<?php
$post_type = 'albums';

$args= array(
  'post_type'      => 'attachment',
  'post_status'    => 'inherit',
  'post_mime_type' => 'image',
  'fields'         => 'id=>parent',
  'order'            => 'DESC',

  'posts_per_page' => -1
);

// get all image parent post ids
$image_parents = get_posts( $args );

if ( $image_parents ) {

  $parent_posts = get_posts( 'fields=ids&post_type=' . $post_type ); // query
  if ( $parent_posts ) {
    // getting all parent posts by post type that have images
    $parent_posts_with_images  = $parent_posts;
    if ( $parent_posts_with_images ) {
      // loop through all post type posts that have images
      foreach ( $parent_posts_with_images as $post_id ) {

        $args = array(
          'post_parent'    => $post_id,
          'post_status'    => 'inherit' ,
          'post_type'      => 'attachment',
          'post_mime_type' => 'image',
          'orderby' => 'rand',
          'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $images = get_children( $args );
        if ( $images ) {


        foreach ( (array) $images as $image )
                   { ?>

                   <li class="gallery-item">
                       <div class="gallery-image">                       
<?php

    $img_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
        $image = $img_url;

echo '<a href="'.$img_url.'" class="album-img" id="" title="'.$post_title.'" >
<img src="'.$image.'" alt=""/></a>';
                 ?>
                      </div>
                 </li>
         <?php }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
 ul#gallery{width:100%;height:100%;position:relative;background:white}
 ul#gallery li.gallery-item{width:20%; height:200px;overflow;hidden;}
 li.gallery-item .gallery-image{ width:100%;height:100%;}
 li.gallery-item .gallery-image img { width:100%;height:100%;display:block}
```

In this way i am getting all 50 images (e.g 5 post with 10 image attached to each gallery) on front end. Now instead of getting all gallery images on display page I want only first image from each gallery attached to parent post of custom post type.And want to use this first image to initialize my light-box/color-box or  any other slider after click on this first image. help me to modify my code .

If i have created 5 post in custom post type like(car,bike,nature,fashion,logo) with respective image gallery attached to those post.Then i want initially to display only first image of car , bike ,nature,fashion and logo.

Comment: If you're limiting the amount of images returned isn't that helping?
`          'posts_per_page' => -1
        );
        $images = get_children( $args );
        if ( $images ) {
` => `'posts_per_page' => 1`

Comment: Yeah! using 'order_by ='menu_order' and 'posts_per_page' => 1  display only first image of gallery. But my question is can I initialize any slider or light box gallery view  using Bunch of respective images .

Comment: I dont want to limit the images from gallery display, just I want to initially display first image and hide other images ,same as what most of image sliders normally do.

Comment: Oh, so add a Boolean variable that checks if it's the first run in the loop (first image), if not add a "hidden" class. `.hidden{display:none}`. Please notice that it depends on the slider's script you're using and its implementation instructions.

Comment: I can manage my slider or lightbox gallery ,once i come to know how can I catch my first image from bunch of gallery image. Getting it from array of $images is main task

Comment: I must say I didn't really understand what you want. but after you set the `$images` array, you can use: `$images[0]->ID` to get the ID of the first image.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion ! i tried it before posting here. but i failed to get first image using $images[0]->ID  . whats wrong in my code?

Comment: 1. Are you using it after `$images = get_children( $args );`?
2. What's the output of `var_dump($images)`?

Comment: I am getting the lengthy array key values :array(1) { [2347]=> object(stdClass)#1184 (24) { ["ID"]=> int(2347) ["post_author"]=> string(1) "1" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2014-02-10 12:16:26" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2014-02-10 12:16:26" ["post_content"]=> string(0) "" ["post_title"]=> string(7) "1638478" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "inherit" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(7) "1638478" ["to_ping"]=> string(0) "" ["pinged"]=> .......

Comment: Oh, the post's id is the key. So use the following:
`$firstimage = reset($images);` -> returns the first value of the array.
`echo $firstimage->ID;` -> the id of the post (object)

Comment: i just referenced this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978879/get-first-image-on-custom-post-type is this helpful